# Как открыть другую вкладку с "id" полученным из php?

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу открыть вкладку с id пользователя, и считать его через $_GET на другой странице для дальнейших манипуляций с БД. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Получается лишь только задать href, которая открывается лишь только в консоли разработчика. Как решить ее?

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '0000', 'cars');
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Ошибка: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,login, password FROM authorized WHERE login='$login' AND password='$pass'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $page = "<a href=wow.php/".$id."'>".$id."</a></br>";
        echo $page;
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете ссылку с неверным форматом URL вместо использования знака вопроса для передачи параметров `GET` вы используете знак слеша, что приводит к неверному URL-адресу.

Замените это

```
$page = "<a href=wow.php/".$id."'>".$id."</a></br>";
```

На это

```
$page = "<a href='wow.php?id=".$id."'>".$id."</a></br>";
```

И потом в `wow.php` можно получить значение параметра `id` из массива `$_GET`

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: А есть какая то возможность открывать эту ссылку в новом окне?